# C# Recursion error?

Tags: c#, recursion, methods

i have really weird problem. I'm using recursive method which is supposed to rotate through 6 players (5 bots and 1 player),however it doesn't do exactly this once it reaches the bot 5 (which is the last one) it skips the player's turn and goes to bot 1 , bot 2 ,bot 3 ,bot 4 ,bot 5 and than it's the player's turn in other words it skips one of the player turn. I'm going to raw paste the code here and if something is unclear explain in the comments.

```
        private async Task Turns()
    {
        turns = ReturnTurns();
        GC.KeepAlive(Updates);
        if (!PFturn && Chips > 0)
        {
            if (Pturn)
            {
                call -= PreviousCalls.PreviousPlayerCall;
                pbTimer.Visible = true;
                pbTimer.Value = 1000;
                t = 60;
                up = int.MaxValue;
                Timer.Start();
                bRaise.Enabled = true;
                bCall.Enabled = true;
                bRaise.Enabled = true;
                bRaise.Enabled = true;
                bFold.Enabled = true;
                turnCount++;
                B1turn = true;
            }
        }
        if (PFturn || !Pturn || Chips <= 0)
        {
            if (pStatus.Text.Contains("Fold"))
            {
                B1turn = true;
            }
            if (!Pturn)
            {
                await Flip(0);
            }
            pbTimer.Visible = false;
            bRaise.Enabled = false;
            bCall.Enabled = false;
            bRaise.Enabled = false;
            bRaise.Enabled = false;
            bFold.Enabled = false;
            Timer.Stop();
            if (!B1Fturn && B1turn)
            {
                int previous = PreviousCalls.PreviousBot1Call;
                call -= PreviousCalls.PreviousBot1Call;
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.ThinkCheck)
                {
                    AutoCloseMsb.Show("Bot 1 Turn", "Turns", ThinkTime);
                }
                Combinations(2, 3, ref b1Type, ref b1Power, b1Status);
                Ai(2, 3, ref bot1Chips, ref B1turn, ref B1Fturn, b1Status, b1Power, b1Type, ref previous);
                await CheckTextBoxes();
                B1turn = false;
                turnCount++;
                B2turn = true;
                PreviousCalls.PreviousBot1Call = previous;
            }

            if (B1Fturn)
            {
                turns = ReturnTurns();
                B2turn = true;
            }
            await Flip(1);

            if (!B2Fturn && B2turn)
            {
                int previous = PreviousCalls.PreviousBot2Call;
                call -= PreviousCalls.PreviousBot2Call;
                Combinations(4, 5, ref b2Type, ref b2Power, b2Status);
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.ThinkCheck)
                {
                    AutoCloseMsb.Show("Bot 2 Turn", "Turns", ThinkTime);
                }
                Ai(4, 5, ref bot2Chips, ref B2turn, ref B2Fturn, b2Status, b2Power, b2Type, ref previous);
                await CheckTextBoxes();
                B2turn = false;
                turnCount++;
                B3turn = true;
                PreviousCalls.PreviousBot2Call = previous;
            }
            B3turn = true;
            if (B2Fturn)
            {
                turns = ReturnTurns();
                B3turn = true;
            }
            await Flip(2);

            if (!B3Fturn && B3turn)
            {
                int previous = PreviousCalls.PreviousBot3Call;
                call -= PreviousCalls.PreviousBot3Call;
                Combinations(6, 7, ref b3Type, ref b3Power, b3Status);
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.ThinkCheck)
                {
                    AutoCloseMsb.Show("Bot 3 Turn", "Turns", ThinkTime);
                }
                Ai(6, 7, ref bot3Chips, ref B3turn, ref B3Fturn, b3Status, b3Power, b3Type, ref previous);
                await CheckTextBoxes();
                B3turn = false;
                turnCount++;
                B4turn = true;
                PreviousCalls.PreviousBot3Call = previous;
            }

            if (B3Fturn)
            {
                turns = ReturnTurns();
                B4turn = true;
            }
            await Flip(3);

            if (!B4Fturn && B4turn)
            {
                int previous = PreviousCalls.PreviousBot4Call;
                call -= PreviousCalls.PreviousBot4Call;
                Combinations(8, 9, ref b4Type, ref b4Power, b4Status);
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.ThinkCheck)
                {
                    AutoCloseMsb.Show("Bot 4 Turn", "Turns", ThinkTime);
                }
                Ai(8, 9, ref bot4Chips, ref B4turn, ref B4Fturn, b4Status, b4Power, b4Type, ref previous);
                await CheckTextBoxes();
                B4turn = false;
                turnCount++;
                B5turn = true;
                PreviousCalls.PreviousBot4Call = previous;
            }
            if (B4Fturn)
            {
                turns = ReturnTurns();
                B5turn = true;
            }
            await Flip(4);

            if (!B5Fturn && B5turn)
            {
                int previous = PreviousCalls.PreviousBot5Call;
                call -= PreviousCalls.PreviousBot5Call;
                Combinations(10, 11, ref b5Type, ref b5Power, b5Status);
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.ThinkCheck)
                {
                    AutoCloseMsb.Show("Bot 5 Turn", "Turns", ThinkTime);
                }
                Ai(10, 11, ref bot5Chips, ref B5turn, ref B5Fturn, b5Status, b5Power, b5Type, ref previous);
                await CheckTextBoxes();
                B5turn = false;
                turnCount++;
                Pturn = true;
                PreviousCalls.PreviousBot5Call = previous;
            }
            if (B5Fturn)
            {
                turns = ReturnTurns();
                Pturn = true;
            }
            await Flip(5);
            if (!restart)
            {
                await Turns();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this make sense? How can using recursion work for a "round robin" - surely you are going to overflow the stack at some point...? Don't you want a state machine (or just a loop?)

Comment: You should work on making a [mcve] to post here. This code is full of info that looks like it doesn't matter to solving the specific problem, and the process of making an mvce might even help you figure out what the problem is by yourself.

Comment: I placed a breakpoint on the `await Turns()` line and once it reaches it it goes 3 lines down and just returns to the if's under `        if (PFturn || !Pturn || Chips <= 0)` it doesn't even check if it's correct

Comment: I need something that will just loop through the 6 players until some statement is fulfilled

Comment: What about... a loop? Not trying to be smart or anything but you just said "I need something that will loop". A really simple state machine would work (just keep the current state "player,bot1,bot2,bot3,bot4..etc") and act accordingly. It looks like a card game, card game rules are very easy to write since they are usually very finite

Comment: Here's an idea - create a `Bot` class, have that class accept the "state" of the card game (create a `CardGame` class which contains the game state). Pass the state to the `Bot` and have it act accordingly - write your logic in that class. Once done, put x number of bots in a `List<T>` on a `GameEngine` class which runs the game loop and just loop over that, passing the game state to each one. The bots can mutate the game state which means the next bot along will make decisions based on the previous bots actions.

Comment: Thanks i will do this or at least i will try

Comment: You should probably implement an interface to allow the player and the bots to both work in the same way, I'll post an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to approach this in a more stateful way. A simplified example may be:

```
// Player interface - the game engine will pass game state to the TakeTurn method
// The target of the TakeTurn call can mutate the game state
public interface IPlayer {

    void TakeTurn(GameState state);

    // Some info that other bots/players might need to look at
    int Chips { get; } 

    // also add other useful bits of info that other game components may need
    int SomeOtherUsefulInfo { get; }
}

public class GameState {

    // Is the game over?
    bool GameOver;

    // State information the bots/player will use to make decisions
    int ChipsInPot;

    // Reference to previous player which could help with AI decisions etc
    IPlayer previousPlayer;          
}

// Both Bot and Human class implement IPlayer which means they can both
// be handled by the same game pipeline step but have radically different
// implementations - such as AI or manual interaction
public class Bot : IPlayer {
    // AI here making sure to implement the IPlayer interface
}

public class Human : IPlayer {
    // Human player handling code but with same interface
}

// Game engine simply runs a loop to keep passing turns
public class GameEngine {
    GameState _state;
    List<IPlayer> _players;

    public GameEngine() {
       _players = new List<IPlayer>();
       _players.Add(new Bot("Fred"));
       _players.Add(new Bot("James"));
       _players.Add(new Bot("Arnold"));
       _players.Add(new Human("Jake")); 
    }

    public void GameLoop() {

        while(!_state.GameOver) {
          foreach(var player in _players) {
              player.TakeTurn(_state); // etc - keep mutating state and looping until the game ends

              // Add more complexity here :)
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's mostly pseudocode as I've missed off a few `public`s here and there but hopefully it gives you an idea of an alternative approach - ah forgot to add any `IPlayer` instances to the list, updated :)

Comment: oh 1 question i started reviewing it just before 10 minutes and im not quite sure how to add new object in the `List<IPlayer>` also where should i put my methods for the bots logics also other methods for checking some other stuff

Comment: You need to add `IPlayer` interface instances to the list - methods for the bots logic can go wherever it needs to go (such as an AI helper class or something) but certainly the main place to start that logic would be from the `TakeTurn` method in the `Bot` class. Game logic can go in the `GameEngine` class or more helper classes. It's up to you how you lay it out, but the main game loop is much simpler using an interface (you could just use an if statement if you wanted, but this is pretty much exactly what interfaces are for - a common contract with different implementations)